# Issue in Ckeditor due to invalid markup of style tag in div

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

There is an issue in Ckeditor-4 due to invalid markup of style tag in div.
Enter the below HTML in ckeditor source and click on source again to move to the Visual Interface. And now ckeditor will get hanged. Can this issue be solved ?

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10%;>
    <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:19px ;">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: WFM. I guess that you use some outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be only achived by editing the [htmlParser](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/htmlparser.html#CKEDITOR-htmlParser) logic by changig the regexp and subsequently modifying the attributes handling.
Or you could just identify the invalid html and fix it on the backend before serving it to ckeditor. I guess a one-time regex fix would be easier :)